# WEB API-REST (php)

Tags: php, веб-программирование, asp.net, api, rest

У меня есть мобильное приложение, к которому я хочу написать **закрытое** WEB API-REST предположительно на  php, так как есть возможность воспользоваться веб-хостингом.

Подскажите:

1. Какие есть основные паттерны для проектирования подобного API?
2. Стоит ли использовать версионность API?
3. Рекомендуется ил использовать ASP.NET Web API?
4. Для чего нужен контролёр или контролеры?
5. Для чего нужны какие то вью?
6. Если можно, покажите эскиз строения архитектуры самого API.

Желательно, краткий и понятный ответ, если можно. Который смог бы служить ориентиром и маяком,  как звездное небо для моряков.

Пример ответа ( для тех кто думает, что, чтобы ответить, нужно написать  целую эпопею):

1. Основные паттерны: 1.... 2.... 3.... 4...
2. Да, стоит. Потому что, так и так....
3. Да , потому что  так и так....
4. Он выполняет такуй ту - такуй ту функцию .... и служит для того то для того... Что бы не было того-то того-то....
5. Используется для того то .... для того  .... Если не использовать, будет то то .... и то то....
6. Вот пожалуйста - рисунок

---

С уважением, П.П.Алексеев.

Comment: Чтобы развернуто ответить на ваш вопрос, нужно привести 3-4 страницы текста. Может у вас получится как-то локализовать проблему или же разбить на отдельные вопросы?

Comment: Согласен с Дмитрием. Краткий и понятный ответ дать нельзя, потому что тут 6 вопросов. Предлагаю вам выделять конкретные вопрсосы, на которые можно дать объективные и аргументированные ответы. Каждый из таких вопросов задавайте как отдельный вопрос. Подробнее можно почитать в справке: [ask].

Answer (score 2):

> Какие есть основные паттерны для проектирования подобного API?

Без комментариев.

> Стоит ли использовать версионность API?

Если api закрытое и все клиенты будут меняться вместе с изменениями api, то нет.

Если клиенты всё-таки не будут меняться, то надо либо поддерживать обратную совместимость api, либо использовать версионность.

> Рекомендуется ил использовать ASP.NET Web API?

Да. Это хорошая платформа, на которой удобно реализовывать REST API. Она сама разбирается с сериализацией и запросами, умеет отвечать и принимать запросы в куче разных форматов.

Насколько я помню, всё уже есть в кросплатформенном варианте .net'а, так что с линуксом проблем быть тоже не должно.

Про другие языки ничего сказать не могу.

> Для чего нужен контролёр или контролеры?

*Контроллеры* в случае web api - это класс, предоставляющий набор публичны методов api (action'ов).

> Для чего нужны какие то вью?

Для api не нужны. А вообще, это представление.

> Если можно, покажите эскиз строения архитектуры самого API.

Без комментариев.

Answer (score 0):

> Какие есть основные паттерны для проектирования подобного API?

Их всего несколько:

---

**1.** *Явное использование HTTP-методов*

```
Для создания ресурса на сервере используется POST.
Для извлечения ресурса используется GET.
Для изменения состояния ресурса или его обновления используется PUT.
Для удаления ресурса используется DELETE.
```

**2**. *Несохранение состояния* Нельзя сохарнять состояние самого девайса. 
   Допустим , онлайн или оффлайн пользователь.  Это делать не реккомендуется в соответствии с HTTP протоколом.

**3**. *Кэширования запросов* - если необходимо это делать. Если допустим мы часто делаем одни и те жи запросы с такими же ответами.

**4**. Отображение URI, аналогичных структуре каталогов
что бы структура URI, соответствовала запросам.

**5.** *Передача XML, JSON или обоих*

**6.**  Поддержка версионности (обязательна) .

Comment: По пункту 1 - все несколько сложнее.

Comment: Да? Мм...xD  А я не знал.

Comment: То есть в общем случае вы полностью правы. Просто стоит упомянуть про эмуляцию `PUT` и `DELETE`, там, где они не поддерживаются.